# How to add html content to a static text in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to display the static content from js and also an image in it

```
content = {
    message: "The best city in the world?"
    answer:" Paris is one of the best city.'<img src ='assets/paris.gif alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">'".
}
```

My Html,

```
 ng-bind-html= content.answer
```

When i run my code,it says the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

This is what i have tried.Can anyone find my error.Thanks.

Comment: Not quoting strings in JS, is that a new thing? Why don't you `'The best city in the world?'` and the same in the other string? Next - read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `content` string doesn't have escape character. When you encapsulate a string with double quote then you can't use it again within the string unless it is with escape character `\`

```
content = {
    message: "The best city in the world?",
    answer: "Paris is one of the best city.'<img src =\"assets/paris.gif \" alt=\"Smiley face\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\">'"
}
```

And if you are using it in angular-template as you have `HTML` in your answer which you want to render, use it with [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Wha you are saying is ,i cant use the double quote again in a double quote?

Comment: You can use but with an escape character like this " name: \"kllp\" " or " name: 'kllp' "

Comment: OHH any how Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
content = {
    message: 'The best city in the world?',
    answer: 'Paris is one of the best city.<img src ="assets/paris.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">.'
}
```

Comment: Hi its my typo mistake when preparing question actually i did it before in my code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code.
variable content should look like this:

```
var content = {
    message: "The best city in the world?",
    answer: 'Paris is one of the best city. <img src ="assets/paris.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">'
}
```

So please use double quotes inside the IMG tag, and single ones in the object property.
Another problem is `{{content.question}}` means nothing, since you have only "message" and "answer" properties inside content.
So you can use `content.message`

Comment: Hi its my typo mistake when preparing question actually i did it before in my code.

Comment: I think you do miss the comma after the message: "blablabla" line. That could cause a Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier error.